# Extracting columns from shapefile into new raster using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.4

Using ArcGIS 10.4

I have a line (shapefile) with lots of information. In 8 columns there are groups of species (Group 1 to Group8), indicating if this is the dominant species group in the area or not. Then for every row there is one group that has a 1 (dominant) and all the other 7 have a 0. In rare cases non of the species groups is dominant (all are 0).

Now, I need ONE raster file with this information. My idea was a raster with the numbers 1 to 8 indicating the dominant species group. But I cant get it to work. First I used feature to raster to extract each of the 8 columns. Then I tried to merge them into one raster with the mosaic to new raster tool. But of course this only gives me a file with 0 and 1 again.

How could I get this done?

Comment: Please provide a picture of a few rows and the row headings in your table to make what you are trying to describe in words clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it. Script will add a new field called DomGroup and add dominant group id. If all groups are 0 id will be 0. Then run feature to raster with new field as input:

```
import arcpy

feature_class = r'C:\folder\shapefile' #Change this to match your shapefile
field_names = ['Group1', 'Group2','Group3','Group4','Group5','Group6','Group7','Group8'] #And this if your fields are named differently
new_field_name = 'DomGroup'
field_names.append(new_field_name)
arcpy.AddField_management(in_table=feature_class, field_name=new_field_name, field_type='LONG')

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature_class,field_names) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if max(row[:-1]) == 0: #Check if there is no dominant species (max value 0)
            row[-1] = 0
        else:
            row[-1] = row[:-1].index(max(row[:-1]))+1 #Find index of max value
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image]

Comment: BERA, your answer helped me in a minute. I double checked, everything is exactly how I need it. Thank you so much!!! I thought there would be an easy way to combine tools. But I guess Python is the only really handy solution for problems like this. Thank you!!!

Comment: Nice! I dont think there is a tool for this.